# Allowing an active directory group to ssh into server

Tags: active-directory, ssh

I'm trying to get my AD group SSH_Users to be able to SSH into our server. I added a line to the config file in /etc/sshd: AllowGroups ssh_Users and tried ssh_Users?domain.com. This does not work. I get an access denied message when trying to log in. I also created a local group called localsshgroup on the server and added the group DOMAIN.COM\ssh_Users to the localgroup. Still the same error. Any help will be great!

Comment: Update: I was able to get the domain admins to be able to log in by using domain?admins but I also have a group called SSH_Users that I want to to be able to log in, and I created a test user and added them, but the user still cannot log into the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently linux removes the upper case letters and puts them to lower case...